# How to separate two block quotes?

Tags: support, markdown

Editing [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1633250/290189), I would like to write two consecutive block quotes without any content in between.

> Definition ...
>
> (Last line of definition)

(I would like a blank line here)

> Theorem ...
>
> (Last line of theorem)

However, as I use

```
> Definition ...

> (Last line of definition)



> Theorem ...

> (Last line of theorem)
```

what I get is one block.

> Definition ...
>
> (Last line of definition)
>
> Theorem ...
>
> (Last line of theorem)

How can I get this result?

[image: An sample output]

Is it possible that the [EOB marker](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#eob-marker) in kramdown, which separates two block elements, be implemented in this site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `&nbsp;` in a line between them.

> This is the first block quote.

> This is the second block quote.

Comment: Thanks.  It's much simpler than my solution.  I'll accept your answer soon.  (I have to wait for 10 min.)

Answer (score 9):

Putting `&nbsp;` in between works, but leaves a lot of empty space. If you prefer less space (as I do), put either an HTML comment `<!-- -->` in between, or any kind of HTML-looking tag for that matter: `<?>` is one of easiest to type, the keys being near each other.

> first block

> second block

The reason this works is that the tags like `<?>` are recognized as not something that SE supports and therefore removed when the post is converted from Markdown to HTML. However, the fact that the tag was there to begin with, causes the parser to terminate one quoteblock and then begin another.

Comment: "the keys being near each other"  Not for everybody. :-)

Comment: Okay, there is probably something else that's near < and >, like a letter that's not one of a,b,i,p,q,s,u (the only one-character HTML tags).

Answer (score 3):

We can directly use HTML without Markdown.

### Result

> Definition ...
>
> (Last line of definition)

> Theorem ...
>
> (Last line of theorem)

### Code

```
<blockquote>Definition ...<br>
<br>
(Last line of definition)</blockquote>

<blockquote>Theorem ...<br>
<br>
(Last line of theorem)</blockquote>
```

Currently, only standard Markdown and a few special tags like `[tag:foo]` are supported.  Since the end-of-block marker (EOB) isn't a part of the standard Markdown syntax, I don't think that Stack Exchange will support this by changing its [Markdown syntax support](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).